# Executing Multiple Operations at once with the EWA API

Tags: javascript, excel, sharepoint-online

We are experiencing major performance difficulties with the ewa (excel web access) api in SharePoint online. Our excel file consists of multiple worksheets, containing named fields only. When reading or writing field values (about 100 at a time), we are performing 100 separate web requests which takes about two minutes in total.

Is there a way of reading / writing multiple field values at once to improve the performance?